# Map & append multiple values (per each key) from a dict to different columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, apply

Having a dict with key-values how can we **map** its values to populate different columns in a dataframe.
Have tried to fill multiple dataframe columns using an **apply** function where the function contains an iteration over range of list of values without success. Any help?

Illustration:

```
{'k1':['v1', 'v2'], 'k2':['v3', 'v4', 'v5']}
```

Desired result (dataframe):

```
    col1  col2  col3
k1  v1    v2
k2  v3    v4    v5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and the [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

d = {'k1':['v1', 'v2'], 'k2':['v3', 'v4', 'v5']}

enum = enumerate(zip_longest(*d.values(), fillvalue=np.nan), 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(enum), index=d).add_prefix('col')
```

An alternative formulation using formatted string literals (Python 3.6+; [PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({f'col{i}': tup for i, tup in enum}, index=d)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   col1 col2 col3
k1   v1   v2  NaN
k2   v3   v4   v5
```

Comment: Great @jpp. And regarding python 2.7+: from itertools import izip_longest ----> Indeed, we need to map that operation with or as an **append** since it should maintain the existent columns in the dataframe. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. We are defining a new dataframe. There's no appending necessary. You can use either `dict` as a constructor or a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: We have created dataframe reading an excel sheet which already has columns we need to maintain; col1, col2, col3 are the new ones we need to map from dict (you have answer correctly); my fault did not detailed it in my question.

Comment: @AbreuFreire, OK.. to combine with another existing dataframe, you can probably use `join` or `concat`, there should be a Q&A somewhere which fits your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, with `join` or `concat` could not yield the desired result/dataframe but with `merge` yes.